# what are the ways to get the return values from model?

Tags: codeigniter

If this is my Model code:

```
function upcome(){
  $query = $this->db->query(" SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE START > DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m-%d' )");
  return $data;
}
```

What should be the Controller?

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html `$data = $this->db->query(" SELECT * FROM ``event`` WHERE START > DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m-%d' )")->result();`

Comment: i need the way to link the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class Upcome_model extends CI_Model {

  function upcome(){
    $data = $this->db->query(" SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE START > DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m-%d' )")->result();
    return $data;
  }


}
```

Controller:

```
$this->load->model('upcome_model');
$data = $this->upcome_model->upcome();
```

Comment: Thanks bro it worked,print_r( $data) working in controller ,but it not working in view page ,because i use the query like this( $data = $this->db->query(" SELECT * FROM event WHERE START < DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m-%d' )")->result(); return $data;) it alrdy retrive the result,i want print the result in view page

Comment: `$this->load->view('view_file', array('events'=>$data));`